# Is there any way to save my 'workspace' in Visio 2013?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I've just got done going through effectively all of the shape options available to me in Visio 2013 for the current project I'm outlining, and selected all of the shapes that I want available to me in my ... Shapes panel...

My question is now this - is there any way that I can save the current 'workspace' if you will ( my selection of usable shapes, at least ) - to be later reusable without the necessity to re-select all 15 or so categories worth of shapes that I'm interested in?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but I bet you can't find it! It used to be easy to find in earlier versions of Visio, but ho-hum.

In Visio 2010 when you click on File on the ribbon you are shown the panel "*Information about* ". On the right you will see a small triangle next to **Properties**, click this and select **Advanced Properties**. At the bottom you will see **Save Workspace**.

Hopefully it is the same or very similar in Visio 2013.

[image]

Comment: It is the same for Visio 13. It seemed that you agreed it was difficult to find, so I wonder why you didn't upvote OP's question..